# Ratio test for sequences and corollary proof attempt

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove the ratio test which states:
Let $a_{0},a_{1},\dots$ be a sequence of positive numbers. Suppose $0 < l < 1$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \leq l$ eventually. Then $(a_{n}) \rightarrow 0$. As a corollary, if $\Big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\Big) \rightarrow a$ with $ 0 \leq a < 1$ then $(a_{n}) \rightarrow 0$

Attempt:

My strategy is to begin with induction. I want to show that $a_{n} \leq l^{n}a_{0}$, I can then use the fact that $l^{n}$ is a null sequence and the shift rule to prove the ratio test. The corollary I'm not too sure on how to prove just yet.

**Induction**

When $n=0$ we have $a_{0} \leq a_{0}$. Inductive step, assume the result is true for $n=k$ i.e. $a_{k} \leq l^{k}a_{0}$. Then $a_{k+1} \leq la_{k}\leq l^{k+1}a_{0}$.

If we assume I have the induction step completed, then we can say that $0 \leq a_{n} \leq 0$ hence it must converge to $0$ for all $n$. If instead, we assume that this holds eventually, then using the shift rule for sequences the result must follow.

**Corollary attempt**

Suppose that $\Big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\Big) \rightarrow a$. For $ 0 \leq a < 1$. Then by definition, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \in \mathbb{N}, |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} - a| < \epsilon,$ for $n \geq N$. I need to then show that $|a_{n}| < \epsilon$ for $n > N$.

some thoughts on how to proceed:

Could I perhaps use the triangle inequality in someway, or the properties of the absolute value function?

Comment: For the induction step, it should read:
$$a_{\bf k} \le l^k a_0 \implies a_{k+1}\le la_k \le l^{k+1}a_0$$

Comment: ah typo initially by me. Thanks.

Comment: Triangle inequality is a good idea, but try proving $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le a+\epsilon<1$ instead. Then you can use the first part.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I managed to solve the problem.